# Typescript Generic, how?

Tags: typescript

I have a function to get all documents from a DB in Firebase
The function itself can be used to retrieve any kind of document, which is why I need to specify whatever it returns with a generic..

Im doing this at the moment:

```
export const getAllDocuments = async <DocType>(collectionName: string) => {
  const documents: DocType[] = [];
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, collectionName));
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    documents.push({
      id: doc.id,
      ...doc.data(),
    });
  });

  return documents;
};
```

But im getting this error: "TS2345: Argument of type '{ id: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DocType'.   'DocType' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{ id: string; }'" ??

Im calling the function like so:

```
const documents = await getAllDocuments<ExerciseDocument>('exercises');
```

What am I doing wrong here? :)

See test example here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8&jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwXAnjAvDA2gWAFAwwDe+hhAlgCYBcMAjKTAL4A0jJBZVtATI0-gC6+fKEiwA5gFMoAQQA28gCIhgAVwC2UsFAgZ4EFGGAwAPABUAfAApEE2tATkwEgJQZLxRmOgxKqzW1dWnMsQX0wgG5GRGQUADoAMxAEAFE4YAALa2t3dE8OMj8ArR0IeIAHNQhswqKYbhgAcjoeAGYmxkImV2jOHr7GBBk1BDBi9VLdPqZBvCA

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/w14JyW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  There should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: The title: "TypeScript Generic, how?" is probably not specific enough; please consider reviewing the guidelines for [ask].

Comment: Perhaps you could define `interface WithId { id: string; }` and restrict `DocType` to extend it using `export const getAllDocuments = async <DocType extends WithId>(collectionName: string) => { /* ... */ };`.

Comment: The problem is not with id... I can push whatever to the array, and i'll get the error, just with whatever property that the item in the array contains... 

I've read the TS docs, and from what I can see, I think im doing it correctly, but obviiously not since it's complaining

Comment: I've setup a test example here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8&jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwXAnjAvDA2gWAFAwwDe+hhAlgCYBcMAjKTAL4A0jJBZVtATI0-gC6+fKEiwA5gFMoAQQA28gCIhgAVwC2UsFAgZ4EFGGAwAPABUAfAApEE2tATkwEgJQZLxRmOgxKqzW1dWnMsQX0wgG5GRGQUADoAMxAEAFE4YAALa2t3dE8OMj8ArR0IeIAHNQhswqKYbhgAcjoeAGYmxkImV2jOHr7GBBk1BDBi9VLdPqZBvCA

Comment: You should [edit] the question with the example as plaintext (a link is a nice supplement but the actual [mre] should be in plain text).  And it should include how you want to call the function too, otherwise I'd say you should just write [this](https://tsplay.dev/mpvbxw).  If you want to be able to specify a generic type parameter somewhere, that belongs in the example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try

```
const getAllDocuments = async <T extends { id: string }>(arg: string) => {
  const documents: T[] = [];
  array.forEach(() => {
    documents.push({
      id: '123'
    } as T);
  });

  return documents;
};
```